# Building retrostyle terminal in opengl

Tags: bash, opengl

I was playing fallout 3 and in that game the computer temrinals ha nice retro touch to them. 
http://www.fallout3nexus.com/imageshare/images/566876-1241715258.jpg

I then got the idea that it would be fun to habe my linux terminal to look and sound that way.

Now to the question. Where would I start looking if I would like to wrap the input/ouput, for example "bash", so that I could build a retrostyle terminal in lets say opengl with bash functionality.

Hope I made the question clear enough. External shell, parse data in and out and present it using some graphics library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XScreensavers ships with a screensaver called *phosphor* which also can be used as a VT220 styler terminal emulator:

```
/usr/lib/misc/xscreensaver/phosphor -pty -scale 2 -delay 1000 -program /bin/bash
```

Take a look at the sourcecode of phosphor to get an idea how to do it. Although this program does not use OpenGL for its effect, the idea and techniques of it apply to an OpenGL version as well.